# I want to extend root partition but unallocated space is on the left side of the root partition

Tags: gparted, partitioning

I am using elementary os, and I need to extend my root partition but the problem is the unallocated space is on the left side of the root partition,
I am new to Linux and I'll appreciate any help

[image]

Comment: What problem are you experiencing?

Comment: I want to extend sda5 with the 22GB unlocated space selected in the image but I can't, I think unlocated space should be on the right side of sda5 to extend it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you extend the partition, you can move it to the left.  This is done by selecting Resize/Move, and then clicking the coloured element that represents the data, and dragging it to the left.

In order to move or resize the root partition, you'll have to load Linux without loading/mounting the root partition.  You can do this by loading up a LiveCD of Ubuntu (or others, like Gparted) and use the tools on the LiveCD to move the partitions.

The easiest way to do this is the find the CD or USB you used to install Ubuntu and boot from that.  Do **not** re-install or install Ubuntu, just use the LiveCD to fix your partitions, and reboot.

Comment: Thanks, It worked